# Prove that if the integral of a function from the same point to two different points is equal, then the function has a root.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

If there exist $c,d\in[a,b]$ such that $c\neq d$ and $\int\limits_a^c f(x)dx =\int\limits_a^d f(x)dx$ then prove that there exists $t\in(a,b)$ such that $f(t)=0$ *(there are further assumptions - see below)*

In the first part of the problem, we assume that $f$ is continuous in [a,b]. I solved the problem by using the mean value theorem for integrals and showing that $\int\limits_c^d f(x)dx=0$ (assuming $c < d$).

Now we assume that $f$ is bounded in $[a,b]$ and continuous in $(a,b)$. I intuitively understand that the problem is essentially the same as in the first part, as the $t$ I found in the first part is neither $a$ nor $b$, and the basic shape of the function (and thus the value of the integral) does not change as the result of the changed assumptions - I am having trouble formalizing the proof, however.

I'd appreciate any help, and I'd especially appreciate general advice on how to translate intuitive understanding to a formal mathematical proof.

Edit: In case it wasn't clear, the assumptions have changed and we now assume that $f$ is bounded in $[a,b]$ and continuous in $(a,b)$. My proof for the first part is longer valid because that MVT only applies when $f$ is continuous in $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'll remark that the Mean Value Theorem for integrals indeed holds when $f$ is bounded and assumed to be continuous only on $(a,b)$:

**Claim:**  Let $f$ be bounded on $[a,b]$ and continuous on $(a,b)$.  Then there is a number $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f(c)={1\over b-a}\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$.

*Proof:* Define the function $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$. Since $f$ is integrable over $[a,b]$, $F$ is defined on $[a,b]$. It follows from the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus that $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. Since $f$ is continuous at any $c\in(a,b)$, it follows, again from the Fundamental Theorem, that $F'(c)$ exists for $c\in(a,b)$ and that for such points  $F'(c)=f(c)$.

So $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$.
We may thus apply the Mean Value Theorem for derivatives to the function $F$ over the interval $[a,b]$. Doing so provides a $c\in(a,b)$ such that
$$
{F(b)-F(a)\over b-a}=F'(c).
$$ 
But, as $c\in(a,b)$, $F'(c)=f(c)$. Moreover $F(a)=0$, and $F(b)=\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$.

The result follows.

---

Secondly, I'll remark that you don't need this theorem to prove your result:

Assume $f$ is bounded, continuous on $(a,b)$ and that $\int_c^d f(x)\,dx=0$ with $d>c$.

Assume, in the hope of obtaining a contradiction, that $f$ does not assume the value $0$ in $(a,b)$. Then since $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$, it must either be positive over $(a,b)$ or negative over $(a,b)$.  Without loss of generality, assume $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$.

Choose $\alpha\in(c,d)$.
Since $f$ is continuous at $\alpha$, there is a nondegenerate  interval $I\subset [c,d]$ with $\alpha\in I$ and $f(x)>f(\alpha)/2>0$ for all $x\in I$.  Now define the function $g:[c,d]\rightarrow \Bbb R$ via $g(x)=f(\alpha)/2$ for $x\in I$ and $g(x)=0$ for $x\in[c,d]\setminus I$.

We have $g(x)< f(x)$ for all $x\in[c,d]$.  Moreover, $g$ is integrable over $[c,d]$ and
$$
0< {f(\alpha)\over 2}\cdot|I|=\int_c^d g(x)\,dx\le\int_c^df(x)\,dx; 
$$
a contradiction.

Comment: "Since $f$ is integrable over $[a,b]$, it follows from the Fundamental Theorem that $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$." Why? Doesn't the Fundamental Theorem only apply when $f$ is continuous in $[a,b]$?

Comment: @Daniel Continuity of $f$ at $c\in[a,b]$ is  required for the differentiability of $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\, dt$ at $c$. Continuity of $F$ only requires that $f$ be integrable.

Comment: But the condition for the Fundamental Theorem is "Let $f$ be a continuous real-valued function defined on a close interval $[a,b]$." How can we even apply the Fundamental Theorem if $f$ is not continuous over $[a,b]$?

Comment: @Daniel There are many versions of the Fundamental Theorem. In it's most general form, most authors do demand that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$; but as I mentioned, this is not needed to prove continuity of $F$ (c.f., item 7.3.5 in *Introduction to Real Analysis*, Barltle and Sherbert, or Theorem 6.20 in Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*).  Only the integrability of $f$ is needed for continuity. In fact, this is easy to show: if $f$ is integrable over $[a,b]$, then it is bounded over $[a,b]$. If $|f(x)|\le M$ for all $x$, then $$\Bigl| \int_x^{x+h} f(t)\, dt \Bigr|\le M|h|$$...

Comment: @Daniel The version of the Fundamental Theorem I'm using is as in Rudin's text (mentioned above): Let $f$ be integrable on $[a,b]$. Define $F(x)=\int_a^b f(t)\,dt$ for $x\in [a,b]$.   Then $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. Furthermore, if $f$ is continuous at $c\in[a,b]$, then $F$ is differentiable at $c$ and $F'(c)=f(c)$.

Comment: Could you please direct me to a proof of that theorem, or edit it into your answer? I've tried looking for it online but haven't found it. If $|\int\limits_x^{x+h} f(t)dt|\leq M|h|$, then why does it follow that $F$ is continuous and not just bounded?

Comment: @Daniel For $f$ integrable, we have for $x,y$ in $[a,b]$ that $|F(y)-F(x)|=\Bigl|\int_x^{y}f(t)\,dt)\Bigr|\le M|x-y|$. So, given $\epsilon>0$, choose $\delta=\epsilon/M$. Then if $x$ and $y$ are in $[a,b]$ with $|x-y|<\delta$, we have $|F(x)-F(y)|\le M|x-y|<\epsilon$.  So $F$ is in fact uniformly continuous over $[a,b]$. (This is the proof from Rudin.)

Comment: @Daniel Or, see Theorem 1 in [these](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/2400int.pdf) notes.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality $d>c:$

$$\int_a^c f(x)\;dx=\int_a^d f(x)\;dx$$

$$\int_a^c f(x)\;dx=\int_a^c f(x)\;dx+\int_c^d f(x)\;dx$$

$$\int_c^d f(x)\;dx=0$$

Since $f$ is bounded, for $x\in (c,d):$

$$\inf_{x\in(c,d)} f\leq f(x)\leq \sup_{x\in(c,d)} f$$

$$(d-c)\inf_{x\in(c,d)} f\leq \int_c^d f(x)dx\leq (d-c)\sup_{x\in(c,d)} f$$

$$\inf_{x\in(c,d)} f\leq 0\leq \sup_{x\in(c,d)} f$$

Since $f$ is continuous there must exist $\lambda\in (c,d)$ such that $f(\lambda)=0$

Comment: I'm not sure the conclusion follows from your last inequality in the second case of the OP. What if $c=a$? In that case, if we only know that $f$ continuous on $(a,b)$, it does not follow that such a $\lambda$ exists from your last inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Why use the MVT for integrals in the first part?

Why not just the observation that $\int_{a}^{c}f(x) dx + \int_{c}^{d}f(x) dx = \int_{a}^{d}f(x)dx ?$

Comment: This is really more of a comment, it doesn't answer my actual question - I've already solved the first part, though arguably not as elegantly as you. It's the second part I need help with.

Comment: As a side note, though, I don't actually understand your comment at all - I proved that $\int\limits_c^d f(x)dx = 0$ in a manner very similar to your's, and then I use the MVT to show that there exists a $t$ such that $f(t) = 0$. Is there a more elegant way to prove it?

Comment: @Daniel It seems you've solved the problem fine - I don't quite understand what your question is.

Comment: @L.F Read the second paragraph - I proved it when we assume that $f$ is continuous, but the assumptions change, and now we assume that $f$ is bounded in $[a,b]$ and continuous in $(a,b)$. My proof is no longer valid because that MVT only works when $f$ is continuous in $[a,b]$.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your phrasing in the original question, thought you were using the MVT to prove the fact that $\int_{c}^{d}f(x)dx=0$!